# Im writing a location sharing app in real time the location of the user but I'm supposed to use firebase to share with other users

Tags: java, android, firebase, real-time

I was able to get the location of the user but i don't know how to upload it to firebase and then share it with another user in real-time.

```
public class MapsActivityy extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_activityy);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Permission to view el location
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                 int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    //check lw el network provider enabled
    //example vodafone or wi-fi
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //bngeeb el actual location
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                // latlng el location 3la el map
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                //initalize class geocoder te3ml convert mn el lat wl lng to an address
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    // 3shan n7ot el address fe list w max el results 1
                    List<Address> addressList= geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
                    String string  = addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+" , ";
                    string +=addressList.get(0).getLocality()+" , ";
                    string +=addressList.get(0).getSubLocality();
                    //Hy7ot marker 3l location
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(string));
                    //3shan n3ml zoom 3l location
                    // el second val hwa amount of zoom
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15.2f));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
        });
    }
    //Satellite
    else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    //bngeeb el actual location
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    // latlng el location 3la el map
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    //initalize class geocoder te3ml convert mn el lat wl lng to an address
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        // 3shan n7ot el address fe list w max el results 1
                        List<Address> addressList= geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
                        String string  = addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+" , ";
                        string +=addressList.get(0).getLocality()+" , ";
                        //if available hygeeb subLoc if not hyb3t null
                       string +=addressList.get(0).getSubLocality();
                        //Hy7ot marker 3l location
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(string));
                        //3shan n3ml zoom 3l location
                        // el second val hwa amount of zoom
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15.2f));

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        });

    }
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
 /*  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/

}
}
```

Comment: Search About Geofire ?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be understood clearly from your description but if you already have the data you can upload and share as follows.
Make sure you have created project and added to your firebase account, imported all the libraries and dependencies and finally copied the JSON service provided to you before starting work with Firebase. You can get detail information here: [Get Started with Analytics for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)

**To Upload Data Firebase.**
Declare variable in your activity as:

```
private DatabaseReference ref;
private FirebaseDatabase minstance;

minstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref = instac.getReference("userData");
Address address = new Address(location, countryname, locality, sublocality);
//as you have a custom arraylist, i hope you already have constructors with the same argument you need to pass data, and getter setter method of all the data variable you need to store in database.

ref.child(String.valueOf(userId)).setValue(address);
//Here the userId works like Primarykey to your database.

ref.child(String.valueOf(userId)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Address address = dataSnapshot.getValue(Address.class);
    }
@Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Failed To Write Data", databaseError.toException());

        }
    });
```

**To Retrieve Data from Firebase**

```
Arraylist<Long> alllocation; //ARRAY LIST TO STORE RETRIEVED DATA
Arraylist<String> allcountry;
Arraylist<String> alllocality;
Arraylist<String> allsublocality;
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userData");
 ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Get map of users in datasnapshot
                collectUserData((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //handle databaseError
            }
        });
```

Now a final loop to add all data with all userId to Arraylist.

```
private void collectUserData(Map<String,Object> users) {

alllocation = new Arraylist<Long>;
allcountry = new Arraylist<String>;
alllocality = new Arraylist<String>;
allsublocality = new Arraylist<String>;

//iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()){

    //Get user map
    Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
    //Get data choosing their field and append to list
    alllocation.add((Long) singleUser.get("location"));
    allcountry.add((String) singleUser.get("country"));
    alllocality.add((String) singleUser.get("locality"));
    allsublocality.add((String) singleUser.get("sublocality"));
   }
}
```